# Additional attributes within a tag to pass values to a function

Tags: javascript, html

```
 <td><img 
    name="Brown Corkboard"
    title="800.00"
    id="nikolas"
    src="materials/corkboardtexture.png"
    alt="600"
    onclick="reply_click(this.src,this.name,this.title,this.alt)"
    width="200"
    height="150"
```

I have this image in an HTML table. I am using the attribues title and alt to specify some values that are needed in performing a function that is called upon clicking the image.

I must be going the wrong way. I want a number of different variables sent to my function upon clicking the image. However i am out of options since i have already used up the title attribute and the alt attribute. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As others have replied, `data-` attributes are the way to go *if* you need to carry arbitrary data in HTML attributes. The `alt` and `title` attributes should not be used for such purposes at all, since that would interfere with the defined meanings and use of those attributes.

The example does not show any reason why you cannot simply write the data as arguments in the function invocation, like `onclick="reply_click(this.src, this.name, 800.00, 600)`.

Or you could write the data in JavaScript object, within or outside the DOM, and make your function just pick them up, using e.g. the `id` attribute value as the key.

Comment: yep no reason at all, i actually did that in the end. thanks a lot

Answer (score 2):

You can add any arbitrary attributes you want, and use them as parameters.

```
<img data-count="1" data-tree="oak" ... onclick=('reply_click(this);')>
```

or whatever you like.

```
function reply_click(clicked_thing) {
    var tree = clicked_thing.getAttribute('data-tree');
    console.log(tree);
}
```

Generally I don't use `onclick` in my image tags, but bind functions to events using javascript.

Comment: doesnt work and i have no idea why. The words are reded out and the values dont get passed.

Comment: not sure what you mean - in the javascript click handler `this` will be the image (the thing that was clicked) and you can get the value of any attribute with `this.getAttribute('attr_name')`.

Comment: <td><img name="Brown Corkboard" title="800.00" id="nikolas" src="materials/corkboardtexture.png" alt="600" newdata="500" onclick= "reply_click(this.src,this.name,this.title,this.alt, this.newdata)" width="200" height="150" </td>      then my function is:     function reply_click(clicked_id,clicked_name,clicked_title,clicked_alt,clicked_newdata)

Comment: modified my answer to include @Smokey's very good recommendation to prefix the attributes with data-*

Comment: Got it guys. Sending the values using the onclick is just plain stupid i guess. Requesting the values using the get attribute works like a charm. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

The standard these days is `data-*`, something such as:

```
<tr data-id="6"><td data-desc="Test blah blah blah">Test</td></tr>
<tr data-id="7"><td data-desc="Gary the disabled penguin">Gary</td></tr>
```

is commonly used. It depends on your exact needs, but I would typically suggest data- attributes

Comment: this doesnt seem to work?! If i put some new word other than the ones specified specifically for an image tag the words just get out in red and the values are not passed.

Comment: What do you mean by "get out in red", how have you implemented this? I would expect something like `<img src="..." data-id="4" data-name="Terry" />`

Comment: exactly like this. When i use an attribute that is specified by HTML rules such as the ''title'' or ''alt'' the words just come out in blue indicating that the syntax is correct. If i use a random word it just comes out in red fonts which means that its not recognized. I implemented it just the way you showed right now. Any ideas on whats going on?

Comment: Come out in red fonts where? Is this your development IDE? Or browser source? A browser addon?